# How do I run a query only asking for a max date of attendance?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm new to SQL and the school I work for wants to run a query on students' transcripts. We want to find out the most recent school the student attended prior to coming to ours. I think I need to use a Max date clause, but I'm not sure. Can someone help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You'll probably get better answers if you post table definitions, sample data, and expected results.

Answer (score 3):

I have to assume some things here because I'm not sure what your table looks like or what your columns are, but let's assume you have a table called `StudentHistory`.

Let's say `StudentHistory` contains the columns `StudentID, StudentName, SchoolName, LeaveDate.`

Each student may have multiple entries depending on how many schools they have frequented. These entries can be ordered by the `LeaveDate` column to get a chronological history of attended schools.

What you want as an output can be articulated as:

> For each student, return the StudentID, StudentName, SchoolName for
>   the last School attended based on the latest LeaveDate.

You can achieve this using the `RANK` function:

```
WITH StudentData AS (
    SELECT StudentID, 
        StudentName, 
        SchoolName, 
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY StudentID ORDER BY LeaveDate DESC) AS TheRank
)
SELECT * 
FROM StudentData 
WHERE TheRank = 1 ;
```